# Курсор и прозрачность области вокруг курсора

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, svg

У меня есть html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="mainvisual.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="main.scss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bg" alt="background"><img src="images/bg.png"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

У меня есть вот часть css кода:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
.bg{
    display: flex;
    content: "";
    justify-content:flex-end;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: .1;
}

bg:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда я перемещаю курсор по экрану, у меня затемненная картинка bg.png с прозрачностью 0,1 становилась полностью прозрачная в радиусе 15 px от курсора. Как это можно реализовать?
На картинку надо наложить маску svg и использовать псевдокласс hover? Или как?

Comment: типа такого ?  http://jsfiddle.net/auxkebvm/

Comment: или это но это эксперементальная фигня : http://jsfiddle.net/r1L25cy4/45/

Comment: третий вариант - http://jsfiddle.net/1wu1ok0d/10/

Comment: Вот это к чему? content не имеет смысла `content: "";`

Comment: ну с трех выше вариантов я что то выберу и изменю) Спасибо за подсказки)

Answer (score 2):

> Я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда я перемещала курсор по экрану, у меня
> затемненная картинка bg.png с прозрачностью 0,1 становилась полностью
> прозрачная в радиусе 15 px от курсора.

Решить это можно с помощью SVG маски круглой формы и затемненного прямоугольника, размещенного поверх фонового изображения.

Маска прорезает этот затемненный прямоугольник и становится видна нижняя картинка.

Привязку курсора к элементу маски осуществляет JS.

```js
$(".image").mousemove(function(e) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
  var posX = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) - 30;
  var posY = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top) - 30;

  $('mask g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + posX + ',' + posY + ')');
});
```

```css
.image {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/secondary/Planet-Nine-443937.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 600 300">
    <mask id="mask">
     
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="white" opacity="0.8" />
      <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
           <!-- Круг элемент маски        -->
       <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="40" />
        
      </g>
    </mask> 
         <!-- Тёмный прямоугольник поверх изображения -->
         <!-- Круглая маска прорезает его и показывает нижнее изображение -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" class="one" mask="url(#mask)" width="600" height="300"  />
  </svg>
</div>
```

- У svg маски есть интересное свойство. Кроме полупрозрачности
  основного элементы можно использовать stroke этого элемента.

`<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="40" fill="black" stroke="green" stroke-width="12" />`

```js
$(".image").mousemove(function(e) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
  var posX = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) - 30;
  var posY = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top) - 30;

  $('mask g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + posX + ',' + posY + ')');
});
```

```css
.image {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/secondary/Planet-Nine-443937.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 600 300">
    <mask id="mask">
     
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="white" opacity="0.7" />
      <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
           <!-- Круг элемент маски + строка другого цвета добавляет полупрозрачность к кругу       -->
       <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="40" fill="black" stroke="green" stroke-width="12" />
        
      </g>
    </mask> 
         <!-- Тёмный прямоугольник поверх изображения -->
         <!-- Круглая маска прорезает его и показывает нижнее изображение -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" class="one" mask="url(#mask)" width="600" height="300"  />
  </svg>
</div>
```

- Курсор в форме бинокля:

```js
$(".a").mousemove(function(e) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
  var relX = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) - 55;
  var relY = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top) - 30;

  $('mask g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + relX + ',' + relY + ')');
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/secondary/Planet-Nine-443937.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="400px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="white" />
      <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" />
        <circle cx="85" cy="30" r="30" />
      </g>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" class="one" mask="url(#mask)" width="400" height="200" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

- Курсор может быть любой формы, например звездочка:

```js
$(".image").mousemove(function(e) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
  var posX = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) - 55;
  var posY = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top) - 55;

  $('mask g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + posX + ',' + posY + ')');
});
```

```css
.image {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/secondary/Planet-Nine-443937.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 600 300">
    <mask id="mask">
     
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="white" opacity="0.7" />
      <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
           <!-- Звезда элемент маски -->
       <path transform="scale(0.6)" d="M100,10 L100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180 z"/>
        
      </g>
    </mask> 
         <!-- Тёмный прямоугольник поверх изображения -->
         <!-- Звезда - маска прорезает его и показывает нижнее изображение -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" class="one" mask="url(#mask)" width="600" height="300"  />
  </svg>
</div>
```